# How to create a launch icon for anaconda-navigator in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: anaconda

I do not have so much experience in Ubuntu and I configured a environment with Anaconda.
But every time I need to open anaconda-navigator I need to do this using terminal.
I would like to have a launch icon for that.
Could someone help me saying how can I do it?